# Keep property from other object to modify by reference

Tags: javascript

I want to keep a property from the `a` instance and modify it in a `b` instance.
Consider the following code

```
class A {
    constructor() {
        this.a = 1
        this.b = 2
    }
}

class B {
    constructor({ a }) { // I want to pass only the a property, not the whole a instance
        this.a = a
    }
    
    addToA() {
        this.a += 1
    }
}

const a = new A()
const b = new B({ a: a.a })

b.AddToA()
console.log(a.a) // here I'd like to have a.a modified here and be 2, but it is 1.
```

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Primitive values are passed by value, not reference. You would have to pass  `a` itself and then modify `this.a.a`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a getter and setter to achieve this. Update your class A and class B like this:

```
class A {
    constructor() {
        this._a = 1;
        this.b = 2;
    }
    get a() {
        return this._a;
    }
    set a(value) {
        this._a = value;
    } } class B {
    constructor({ a }) {
        this._a = a;
    }
    addToA() {
        this._a.a += 1;
    }
    get a() {
        return this._a;
    } } const a = new A(); const b = new B({ a: a }); b.addToA(); console.log(a.a); // Now it will be 2
```

By using a getter and setter, you can pass a reference to the a property and modify it through the B instance.

Comment: Thanks, but I want to pass only the `a` property, not the whole instance. My bad formulating the question.

Comment: Updated in that case

Comment: What programming language is this?

Comment: THat helped, thanks @Leo. Can't I use `a` instead of `_a` in class `B`? It gets overwritten apparently if so.